# Why are many rows of the same name showing in MySQL php?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I tried to INNER JOIN two tables and when I use `'='` it works, but when I use `'!='` it doesn't work anymore. The result is a lot of rows with the same value.

For example

```
name:
john
john
john
john
john
mary
mary
mary
mary
lisa
lisa
lisa
lisa
lisa etc... (many other names)
```

**this is my code.**

```
SELECT part_names FROM participants INNER JOIN reservations ON participants.part_id != reservations.part_id
```

the crazy thing is e.g. that I get 5 John's, 5 Lisa's and only 4 Mary's (mary should not be showing as her participants id does match the one in reservations. How do I solve this that I only get to see the participants whose part_id in table participants doesn't match in the reservations table? and only 1, so not Lisa Lisa Lisa Lisa Lisa but just Lisa. 
thanks!

Comment: Short answer.. `INNER JOIN` connects multiple tables together and can cause complete duplicated results or duplcations in columns..

Comment: okay thank you, i did not know that

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you want a `left join` and comparison to `NULL`:

```
SELECT p.part_names
FROM participants p LEFT JOIN
     reservations r
     ON p.part_id = r.part_id
WHERE r.part_id IS NULL;
```

That is, look for matches and then return the rows with no match.

Comment: thank you so much, it works! I was just wondering if this could be possible without using Join or Left Join, just WHERE?Or is that not possible? It's for school, and maybe I'm only allowed to use the things we've learned in class. thanks, again!!!

Comment: What have you learned in class? @imnotokaypopvidz `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` maybe??

Comment: @RaymondNijland only WHERE

Comment: @imnotokaypopvidz . . . I would usually write this using `NOT EXISTS`.